# React Native Autocomplete input error : Objects are not valid as a react child (found: object with keys)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using react-native-autocomplete-input to display cities name / zip code in a list.

I've a state (villes) with cities infos like this (depending of what i write in the input)

```
villes 
* (18) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Num: 283, Ville: "NIEVRE", CP: 58, Dep: "NIEVRE", DepNum: 58, …} 
1: {Num: 24504, Ville: "NIAFLES", CP: "53400", Dep: "MAYENNE", DepNum: 53, …} 
2: {Num: 24505, Ville: "NIAUX", CP: "09400", Dep: "ARIEGE", DepNum: 9, …} 
3: {Num: 24506, Ville: "NIBAS", CP: "80390", Dep: "SOMME", DepNum: 80, …} 
4: {Num: 24507, Ville: "NIBELLE", CP: "45340", Dep: "LOIRET", DepNum: 45, …} 
5: {Num: 24508, Ville: "NIBLES", CP: "04250", Dep: "ALPES-DE-HAUTE-PROVENCE", DepNum: 4, …} 
6: {Num: 24513, Ville: "NICEY", CP: "21330", Dep: "COTE-D'OR", DepNum: 21, …} 7: {Num: 24514, Ville: "NICEY-SUR-AIRE", CP: "55260", Dep: "MEUSE", DepNum: 55, …}
```

The autocomplete :

```
<Autocomplete
                autoCapitalize="none"
                clearButtonMode={'always'}
                defaultValue={defaultText}
                keyboardType={'ascii-capable'}
                style={{
                    height: 40,
                }}
                autoCorrect={false}
                containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
                listStyle={{maxHeight: 300}}
                data={villes}
                inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
                onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
                placeholder="Ville, CP ou département"
                renderItem={({Ville,CP,Num,Lat,Lng,code_com,ArraySameCP}) => <Text>{Ville}</Text>}
                />
```

The error is "Objects are not valid as a react child (found: object with keys {Num, Ville, CP ...)
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Obviously, i'm searching since yesterday on stack, and tried many things, but could find the solution.

I've this issue since i changed class component to functional component and hooks.
Before, instead of setVilles(arrayCities), i did a setState({villes: arrayCities}) and did not have any problem.

If someone has an idea ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Try using `{JSON.stringify(Ville)}` to see the content of Ville because it is the problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wrote ```renderItem={({Ville,CP,Num,Lat,Lng,code_com,ArraySameCP}) => <Text>{JSON.stringify(Ville)}</Text>}```but still the same issue with objects are not valid react child

Comment: Try to clear cache when you make updates

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the issue.
I was using an old syntax of Autocomplete package (3.6). Because i'm updating a project, i've copy paste the old Autocomplete code, which is not good for the last version i'm using now.
I added FlatListProps to the Autocomplete component, and it works.
Thank you so much for your help ! i really appreciated it.

```
<Autocomplete
                autoCapitalize="none"
                clearButtonMode={"always"}
                defaultValue={defaultText}
                keyboardType={"ascii-capable"}
                style={{
                    height: 40,
                }}
                autoCorrect={false}
                containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
                listStyle={{ maxHeight: 300 }}
                data={villes}
                inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
                onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
                placeholder="Ville, CP ou département"
                flatListProps={{
                    keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'always',
                    keyExtractor: (item, i) => i.toString(),
                    renderItem: ({ item: { Ville, CP } }) => (
                            <Text>{Ville} {CP}</Text>
                    ),
                }}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You are destructuring renderItems in wrong way.

```
<Autocomplete
                autoCapitalize="none"
                clearButtonMode={'always'}
                defaultValue={defaultText}
                keyboardType={'ascii-capable'}
                style={{
                    height: 40,
                }}
                autoCorrect={false}
                containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
                listStyle={{maxHeight: 300}}
                data={villes}
                inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
                onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
                placeholder="Ville, CP ou département"
                renderItem={({item: {Ville,CP,Num,Lat,Lng,code_com,ArraySameCP}}) => <Text>{Ville}</Text>}
                />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! unfortunately i still have the problem. Seems the issue is located in the "villes" state i pass to autocomplete :(

Comment: you can debug using index.js file of autocomplete library itself. It may help in what it is sending in

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with a single variable destructuring and check whether it is working if yes then there must be destructuring issue in your code.

code:

```
<Autocomplete
  autoCapitalize="none"
  clearButtonMode={"always"}
  defaultValue={defaultText}
  keyboardType={"ascii-capable"}
  style={{
    height: 40,
  }}
  autoCorrect={false}
  containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
  listStyle={{ maxHeight: 300 }}
  data={villes}
  inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
  onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
  placeholder="Ville, CP ou département"
  renderItem={({ Ville }) => <Text>{Ville}</Text>}
/>;
```

Comment: Hello ! thank for your answer.
I've tried this, and i've "text strings must be rendered with a <Text> component" seems {Ville} is an object

Comment: have you removed the last semi column from the above code ?

Comment: ops... sorry. I removed it, and still have "objects are not valid as react child"

Comment: now return null in render item and before it console.log(item) and check what is showing in log messages

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution, which is not so clean, in my opinion

```
<Autocomplete
                autoCapitalize="none"
                clearButtonMode={'always'}
                defaultValue={defaultText}
                keyboardType={'ascii-capable'}
                style={{
                    height: 40,
                }}
                autoCorrect={false}
                keyExtractor={(item, i) => i.toString()}
                containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
                listStyle={{maxHeight: 300}}
                data={villes.map((item, index) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity key={index} style={styles.itemText} onPress={() => onPressSugg(item.Ville,item.CP,item.Num, item.Lat, item.Lng,item.code_com, item.ArraySameCP)}>
                        <Text style={styles.suggestion}>
                            {item.Ville} ({item.CP})
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                ))}
                inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
                onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
                placeholder="Ville, CP ou département"
/>
```

Idk why, but i've to render in the data to make things work. I'm continuing to search something cleaner...